# How to run a 'Live' query to a DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I want to populate a control with a query to a DataSet but I want to add new data to the table in the DataSet and update the control with this new data that matches the query.
It's like a live query where I'd like to receive any new row that matches the same query.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just retrieve another dataset that contains the new values and then call the [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k.aspx) method on the original dataset using the new dataset as the parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you mean that I should run the query to the new DataSet and then Merge them? I thought there was another way, I wonder about the performance with this method.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The only other option would be to add each of the rows from the new dataset into the current dataset. There isn't really a more efficient way when working with datasets since they are designed to be used while disconnected from the database.

Comment: Finally, I'm using 2 DataView: one will show changes putting RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.Added | DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent. After processing changes, I use DataTable.AcceptChanges() and works perfect.